# What is the point of DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm writing a small card game with a friend and as of the last year I worked with DDD and love every minute, 
So it felt natural to me to use DDD for our core domain logic of the game.

Doing a little bit of research on best practices to integrate DDD with game logic, I stumbled into this question : [Domain Driven Design approach for game](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370127/domain-driven-design-approach-for-game).

A part of the answer says :

> The point of DDD is to organize code into discrete and non-reusable parts to ensure reliability and predictability.

For some reason, I'm very disturbed with the `non-reusable parts` part, not only have I ever seen those descriptive words about DDD but neither has experienced it.
The impression I got from DDD is of course reliability and predictability, but also extending the behavior of an entity or an aggregate quite easily, I didn't find any DDD way that blocking me from using regular OOP best practices and design patterns.
Setting aside eventual consistency that is not a great fit for real time game, I see no reason that DDD wouldn't work in any game logic or any little more than simple domain logic.

Is the answer I quoted really is the point of DDD ? 
Have I understood the meaning of DDD wrong ?

Comment: I would not take an arbitrary statement like that too literally and don't try to interpret too much into this. My best guess is the answerer just meant "not necessarily reusable" - but TheCatWhisperer hasn't been active on this site since 3 years, so it is unlikely we can ask them what they really had in mind.

Comment: this sounds very familiar : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/443646/doubts-how-to-design-a-card-game-in-ddd/443656#443656

Comment: Reusability is very common in inheritance hierarchies like UI and in functions, methods, classes and libraries.  But a module fundamentally differs from other modules.  The whole point of modularism is to isolate a module so that it can be worked on independently.

Answer (score 6):

With DDD, we’re solving (business) problems that are specific to a single bounded context. We do that, using the language of the domain experts.

Programmers sometimes solve a problem and then make the code more abstract and generic, so that it can be reused elsewhere. That is exactly what should *not* be done when applying DDD. The code needs to remain specific and explicit about what it does. It should not be made *reusable*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I agree that DDD code should be explicit and predictable but why cant it also be `reusable`, for example using a custom discount logic, DDD + Strategy for example wont make the  `predictable` and somewhat `reusable` ?

Comment: Nothing stops your domain layer from being reusable. (And sure, you'll probably use your domain classes all over the place *within your app or ecosystem*.) But, aiming for "reusability" **as a goal** is not nearly as helpful (if at all) as compared to other concerns, like "sorting" or "structured data access".

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fair to say that DDD is most applicable to the "internal" world from Joel Spolsky's 5 worlds: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/05/06/five-worlds/

**Performance**

You have stated your game is a card game (probably turn based).
Hence it's unlikely that performance of the code that manipulates the core model is going to be a significant factor for you.

I suspect most of the "Don't use DDD for games" arguments are built on a performance foundation - for example I doubt DDD would be a good choice for an FPS.

**Is DDD useful in this case?**

Clearly there are different "bounded contexts" between core logic and display/animation. However I am not going to say that's a "win for DDD" if you were to simply separate the application into tradition tiers (Display, Logic and Serialization/Storage) you would end up with the same division.

The literature on DDD (Eric Evans) spends a great deal of time taking about the importance of establishing a common language to describe the domain - with only 2 people on the project, I would hope that that is not a significant challenge for you.

I was originally going to say that I thought the entire state of the game would be a bounded context, but perhaps I am wrong, you might be able to create several contexts such as:

- The mechanics of the game (unplayed cards/deck, hold cards, played cards, turns, etc).
- Game rules - interactions between cards meaning etc.
- Final score - Assuming there is a score - its not just a win/lose situation.

**Should you use DDD?**

I don't see a strong reason not too, if its helpful to you I would say go ahead - I don't think using it is going to force you into a problematic design.

The only caveat I would give is, don't try to use it for performance critical parts, for example if you need to do complex animations.

**non-reusable parts**

> The point of DDD is to organize code into discrete and non-reusable
> parts to ensure reliability and predictability.

If you deleted the words "and non-reusable" from that quote, it's basically describing a bounded context.

**Edit:**

The remainder of my post was incorrect - I have removed the incorrect part please see @RikD's answer for a definition of what was meant by `non-reusable`

Comment: My interpretation of "non-reusable" isn't that not being reusable is the goal, but rather than being reusable *isn't* the goal. A lot of talk about splitting code up into modules is to allow reuse, but here, the explicit goal of modularization *isn't*.

Comment: Can I check my understanding - what I think you are saying is that, some code in a particular bounded context may not be useable/useful/relevant in a different BC - or for that matter any other BC other than the one that the code is placed in. Further DDD does not have a strong opinion on this situation - it may or may not happen, but either situation is fine.

Comment: That's my understanding, yes. DDD says "split your code due to domain constraints, not for efficiency/reuse".

Comment: @RikD's answer puts it more clearly.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan DDD certainly **does** encourage reusable modular code, Eric Evans is simply pointing out that anything which happens to be reusable simply doesn't belong to a Bounded Context in the first place.   (And realistically if something is generic enough to be reusable across multiple BCs then it probably doesn't belong to the domain model at all - e.g. reusable GUI components, networking/socket library, helper/utility classes and functions, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I agree that using DDD is bad for performance, but if I'm using for example Unity or Unreal Engine, why using DDD for FPS is a bad idea ?
If I'm simply using DDD to manage the state of the game, how is that no fitting ?

Answer (score 1):

In any application you write you will have some components specific for that particular application. For a card game that probably includes the rules for that particular game. And it is nothing wrong with this, overly generalized code can easily become impossible to read and understand. In some cases code duplication is fine, even if the code might be identical today, if the domains are different they might diverge in the future.

That does not mean you cannot have code reuse. There are game engines that can be used for any type of game, i.e. a "game" domain. And you can have many "domains" at different levels of abstraction.

But it is also not uncommon with game engines specific for a particular *type* of game. But has the actual rules as input/configuration. That way a non programmer can change or add rules and experiment without having to write a bunch of code.

So there is no reason not to use DDD for a game, but you want to keep in mind that many different domains are involved, the part that handles graphics is a different domain from the game logic etc.